# Running a process multiple times at the same time

Tags: c++, multithreading, opencv, ubuntu, command-line

I have a c++ program with opencv library which takes an image as input and perform pose estimation,color detection,phog. When I run this program from the command line it takes around 4-5sec to complete. It takes around 60%cpu. When I try to run the same program from two different command line windows at the same time the process takes around 10-15 sec to finish and both the process finish in almost the same time. The CPU Usage reaches upto 100%.

I have a website which calls this c++ exe using exec() command. So when two users try to upload an image and run it takes more time as I explained above in the command line. Is this because the c++ program involves high computation and the CPU reaches 100% it slows down? But I read that the CPU reaching 100% is not a bad thing as the computer is using its full capacity to run the program. So is this because of my c++ program or is it something to do with my server(computer) settings? This is probably not the apache server problem because when I try to run it from the command line also it slows down. I am using a quad core processor and all the 4 CPU reaches 100% when I try to run the same process at the same time so I think that its distributed among all the processor. So I have few more questions:

1) Can this be solved by using multithreading in my c++ code?As for now I am not using it but will multithreading make the c++ code more computationally expensive and increase the CPU usage(if this is the problem).

2) What can be the reason of it slowing down? Is the process in a queue and each process is ran only a certain amount of time and it switches between the two process?

3) If this is because it involves high computation will it help if I change some functions to opencv gpu functions?

4) Is there a way I can solve this problems any ideas or tips?

I have inserted the result of top when running one process and running the same process twice at the same time:

Version5 is the process,running it once
[image]
Two Version5 running at the same time
[image]

The CPU info:
[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Without actually seeing your code, it's hard to say exactly what the code is doing... But it seems a bit suspect.

Comment: It would also help a lot to understand what your CPU's are. For example an Intel hyperthreading processor will behave differently to a processor with "four real cores".

Comment: I have added my CPU details.

Comment: How is it performing, when Version5 running once is ran in a loop

Comment: I take it you haven't heard of copy/paste of text?

Comment: @AnoopK.Prabhu when I run the Version5 in a loop one at a time its ok. It takes 5sec each.

Answer (score 2):

After zooming so that your picture fills almost my entire 22" screen, I can make out that the CPU flags show "ht", which means "hyperthreading", so you actually only have two genuine cores, that are shared between two hyperthreads. So running on all four CPU cores at once will not give the same performance as running on two genuine cores.

In other words, the "loss of performance" is entirely as you'd expect, because you have four threads fighting for the actual computational resources of two CPU cores. Hyperthreading helps if the code has a lot of memory interaction that can be "hidden" by running a second thread. But if you have a CPU intensive code, that isn't "missing in the cache" much, then the gain is much less, and in extreme cases, hyperthreading will actually cause slow-downs (because the code in one thread disrupts the caches and otherwise "gets in the way" of the first thread). You may want to experiment by going into the BIOS settings and turn off the hyperthreading, and compare the results. Sure, running two instances of the code will clearly still take longer, but the question is "is it longer than running with hyperthreading" - unfortunately, it's impossible to say for sure which is better from a theoretical standpoint (even if I could see the assembly code and understood the memory access patterns - without that level of detail, it's completely impossible to judge).

Answer (score 1):

1. When running only one process reaches 60% of CPU usage it would be possible that using multithreading speeds up the execution. However, the CPU usage is likely to be higher
2. That's true. There might be an additional overhead for context switching (multitasking)
3. Changing functions can bring some improvements, but without having your code it is hard say.
4. Since the computational effort is that high, I think you have to decide whether you accept a high CPU usage or a longer execution time (of course after optimizing the code itself)

Greetz